# Validate password in sudo command

Tags: linux, command, sudo

How do I validate the password I've given in the following `sudo` command against the mentioned user?

```
sh -c "echo <password> | sudo -u <username> <command/script>"
```

This command is working for me even when I'm giving incorrect passwords.

---

Based on comment made by @NikosC.

By "validate", I mean that the system should make sure I am giving the correct password. Lets assume - password for  is **password**. If i give password as **blahblah** instead of **password**, it still works.

Comment: if you pass `-u YOUR_USER_NAME` it won't ask you for password. Also you need to pass `-S` option to read password from STDIN.

Comment: Is there anyway I could achieve what I've mentioned in my question? My requirement is I need to mention both username and password and also validate them.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "validate"? sudo already does that, obviously.

Comment: @NikosC. by "validate", I mean that the system should make sure I am giving the correct password. Lets assume - password for **username** is **password**. If i give password as **blahblah** instead of **password**, it still works.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, that's because sudo on your system is configured to take the source user password instead of the target user one. And since sudo caches the password for about 5 minutes, no password is needed for subsequent calls.

Comment: Oh, the `-k` option is useful for invalidating cached credentials so that sudo will always require a password. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell sudo to read the password from standard input using the `-S` option, and to not take into account cached credentials from previous authentications using the `-k` option. Also, you should be able to just use a pipe directly without the need to spawn a new shell. So just do:

```
echo password | sudo -k -S -u username command/script
```

There's a few things to note. First, most systems have configured sudo in a way to take the current user's password, not the target user's one. To configure sudo to read the target user's password instead, you must set:

```
Defaults targetpw
```

In your sudo configuration (/etc/sudoers or a file in /etc/sudoers.d/).

Comment: As I understand @user1649068 wants to pass username's password, not password of current user. sudo takes password of current user, not the username's password.

Comment: @loentar sudo takes the password of the user you configured it to take. This can be the target user or the current user.

Comment: well, then try to start this script with username's password and look at result!

Comment: @loentar If you configure sudo to take the target's password, then it will work. This done by setting `Defaults targetpw` in /etc/sudoers

Comment: Sure, but you must change system files.